# Не отображается текстура OpenGL ES2 Android

Tags: java, opengl, opengles

Вот код, который реализует вывод текстуры на экран, но вместо нее выводит черный прямоугольник.

```
static ShaderProgram shaderProgram;
private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
private FloatBuffer textureBuffer;
private int textures[] = new int[1];

private float vertices[] = {
        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f
};

private float texture[] = {
        0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f
};

public Sprite(String path) {
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
    byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    vertexBuffer = byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
    vertexBuffer.put(vertices);
    vertexBuffer.position(0);

    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(core.getAssets().open(path));
    } catch (IOException e) { }

    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

    byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(texture.length * 4);
    byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    textureBuffer = byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
    textureBuffer.put(texture);
    textureBuffer.position(0);
}

public void draw() {
    shaderProgram.use();
    GLES20.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

    int positionAttrib = shaderProgram.getAttribLocation("vertices");
    int textureUniform = shaderProgram.getUniformLocation("tex");
    int textureAttrib = shaderProgram.getAttribLocation("texCoord");

    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionAttrib);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(textureAttrib);

    GLES20.glUniform1i(textureUniform, 0);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(positionAttrib, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, vertexBuffer);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(textureAttrib, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, textureBuffer);

    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, vertices.length / 3);

    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(positionAttrib);
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(textureAttrib);
}
```

Vertex shader

```
#version 150
in vec3 vertices;
in vec2 texCoord;
out vec2 fTexCoord;

void main() {
    fTexCoord = texCoord;

    gl_Position = vec4(vertices, 1);
}
```

Fragment shader

```
#version 150
uniform sampler2D tex;
in vec2 fTexCoord;
out vec4 finalColor;

void main() {
    finalColor = texture(tex, fTexCoord);
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте локализовать ошибку, вставляя в код вызов `glGetError` и проверку его значения. Место очередной вставки определяйте методом деления пополам. Так вы найдёте проблемную строку.

Comment: Пробовал, всегда возвращает 0.

Answer (score 2):

[Из википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_Shading_Language):

> В GLSL 1.30 и новее используется следующая функция:
>
> ```
> glBindFragDataLocation(Programm, 0, "MyFragColor");
> ```
>
> где: Programm — указатель на программу; 0 — номер буфера цвета, если
>   вы не используете MRT(Multiple Render Targets), значение должно быть
>   равно 0; «MyFragColor» — имя выходной переменной шейдерной программы,
>   записывающей в данный буфер.
>
> ```
> #version 150
> void main(void)
> {
>     MyFragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
> }
> ```

---

Или воспользоваться старым синтаксисом и написать так:

Fragment shader

```
#version 150
uniform sampler2D tex;
in vec2 fTexCoord;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor= texture2D(tex, fTexCoord);
}
```

Тоже должно работать.